# MSAL - Python - Multi-Tenant Web APP - aad.config.json

Tags: python, django, authentication, nginx, azure-ad-msal

We have successfully gotten our Django + Nginx + MySQL web app hosted and auth working through Azure with O365 for mailing using graph & O365 EWS. We have two different redirect URI's 1 for a dev environment and the other for prod. Both seem to work fine with both being up at the same time. The issue we are running into is the AAD.config.json, I authorized and got all the way through MFA with the external tenant account. The APP Registration in hosted tenant Azure/Entra shows supported account types: multiple organizations and verified the Publisher with the MPN ID.

Whenever I try logging in with External Tenant (user's added to User & groups with default access  role assigned in Hosted Tenant's AD) I receive the following:

AuthCanceled at /social-auth/complete/azuread-oauth2/

Authentication process canceled

During handling of the above exception (400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token), another exception occurred:

Below is the `aad.config.json` taken from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-samples-common/blob/main/aad.django.config.json

```
{
    "type": {
        "client_type": "CONFIDENTIAL",
        "authority_type": "MULTI_TENANT",
        "framework": "DJANGO"
    },
    "client": {
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"
    },
    "auth_request": {
        "redirect_uri": null,
        "scopes": [],
        "response_type": "code"
    },
    "flask": null,
    "django": {
        "id_web_configs": "MS_ID_WEB_CONFIGS",
        "auth_endpoints": {
            "prefix": "auth",
            "sign_in": "sign_in",
            "edit_profile": "edit_profile",
            "redirect": "redirect",
            "sign_out": "sign_out",
            "post_sign_out": "post_sign_out"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone is running into this issue, please use https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp-django/tree/main as the new repo for Django Auth. It will work better than the social-app-django as that and azure-identity are now deprecated.